# AccessViolation

Tags: c#, string, pinvoke, dllimport, access-violation

I keep getting an AccessViolationException when calling the following from an external C DLL:

```
short get_device_list(char ***device_list, int *number_of_devices);
```

I set up a DLLImport declaration as such:

```
[DLLImport("mydll.dll")]
static public extern short get_device_list([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref string[] devices, ref int number_of_devices);
```

My C# application code:

```
{
string[] devices = new string[20];
int i = 0;
short ret = 0;
ret = get_device_list(ref devices, ref i); // I receive the AccessViolation Exception here
// devices[0] = "2255f796e958f7f31a7d2e6b833d2d426c634621" which is correct.
}
```

Although I receive the exception, the device array gets filled correctly with the 2 UUIDs of the devices connected (and also gets resized to size = 2; i is also 2;).

What is wrong?

PS: After a long research I also tried:

```
[DLLImport("mydll.dll")]
static public extern short get_device_list(ref IntPtr devices, ref int number_of_devices);
```

and

```
{
IntPtr devices = new IntPtr();
int i = 0;
short ret = 0;
ret = get_device_list(ref devices, ref i); // No AccessViolation Exception here
string b = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(devices); // b = "歀ׄ", which is incorrect
}
```

but that did not help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you really sure you have `char ***` and not `char **`?  `char ***` implies an array of arrays (well, a pointer to a pointer to a pointer)...

Comment: Peter: yes, I am sure it is char*** ..

Comment: @manuelw - If you really do have `char***` then your two signatures do not match.  Your C# code is only equal to `char**` the two much be equal.  You need send a reference to the pointer of the array to be equal to your C code.  I also suggest you make the calling conventions equal.

Comment: Could you please post the API description what is expected in parameter: char ***device_list As I read it the DLL wants a pointer to a pointer of an array of string pointers. Who allocates the strings/array is the big question. Maybe you should just give the dll the place where to put the resulting pointer of the array the DLL created.

Comment: @Ramhound - ok, but how do I send a reference to the array pointer?
@BlueM - In C++ I just used `char** device_list = NULL` and `get_device_list(&device_list, &i);`. This works like a charm.

Comment: Then its clear that the DLL allocates the memory for you. This wasnt clear to me from your description. All you have to supply to that dll is a pointer to an IntPtr. That IntPtr will get filled with a pointer to an array of strings.

Comment: `string b = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(devices); // b = "歀ׄ", which is incorrect` Was `i` set to > 0 after the call returned? What you basically do there is to read the first element of the devices string array which should work for the first element.

Comment: @BlueM - yes `i` was set to 2 as expected, because there are two devices connected.

Comment: Your problem was that you have to handle the pointer as a pointer to an ARRAY of strings not as a pointer to a string ;-)

Comment: Yes, I do understand now, I was totally confused. :-D
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DLLImport("mydll.dll")]
static public extern short get_device_list(out IntPtr devices, 
    out int number_of_devices);
```

Is the best way to tackle this. The memory is allocated and owned on the native side of the interface. The trick is how to get at it. Something like this should work.

```
static public string[] getDevices()
{
    IntPtr devices;
    int deviceCount;
    short ret = get_device_list(out devices, out deviceCount);
    //need to test ret in case of error

    string[] result = new string[deviceCount];
    for (int i=0; i<deviceCount; i++)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(devices, typeof(IntPtr));
        result[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        devices += IntPtr.Size;//move to next element of array
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your code was using [`PtrToStringAuto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewyktcaa) but that's going to interpret the data as `UTF-16` encoded. But your C++ code uses `char*` which is 8 bit ANSI. So you need [`PtrToStringAnsi`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe). OK, there's an assumption here that the encoding is not UTF-8, but that's a detail I cannot provide. It's easy enough to adapt this to UTF-8.

You should also double check that the native code uses the `stdcall` calling convention and isn't using `cdecl`.

Comment: Now I see it :-). The DLL allocates the memory as it seems. The number of devices is returned by that DLL so the caller knows how big the array is which was allocated. But who frees that memory?

Comment: @BlueM D'oh! I just assumed that since you were asking!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The code works, but I still cannot receive the real uuid string .. `deviceList[0] = "¨pˆ"`
I guess there is a problem at the PointerToString conversion.. :-/

Comment: No, I made a mistake. Missing a de-reference. Will update. Nearly there!

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now. `devices` is a `char**`. In other words, an array of `char*`. I was missing a de-reference to go from `char**` to `char*`. The `PtrToStructure` adds that. Code taken from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/11/05/dereference-a-double-intptr.aspx

Comment: That's good to hear, and thanks for the accept. These type of questions are my favourite questions on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Ok I think I know the problem in your second attempt.

```
{
IntPtr devices = new IntPtr();
int i = 0;
short ret = 0;
ret = get_device_list(ref devices, ref i); // No AccessViolation Exception here
string b = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(devices); // b = "歀ׄ", which is incorrect
}
```

You try to convert a pointer to an array of strings to a string. You have to deference it first. Please check whether this works for you:

```
  IntPtr devices = new IntPtr();
  int numDevices = 0;      
  short ret = get_device_list(ref devices, ref numDevices); // No AccessViolation Exception here
  for (int i=0; i<numDevices; i++)
  {
    IntPtr ptrToString = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(devices);
    string deviceString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrToString);
    devices += IntPtr.size;
    Console.WriteLine(deviceString);
  }
```

Comment: EDIT: no, i don't think this is the problem. get_device_list reinitializes the string array automatically and resizes it to the number of all connected devices (which is 2).

Comment: So you get sporadically AccessViolation and already got the array filled? Would be new string[0] enough and it still works?

Comment: @BlueM - Your explaination of the reason this isn't working is NOT correct.

Comment: I know. As the signature of the function suggests he should deliver a pointer to a pointer to an array of strings. I'm not sure whether these strings have to be initialized.

Comment: @BlueM Yes, i tried it with `string devices = new string[0]` and i also tried it `string[] devices = null` (the array gets also reinitialized here), but i always get AccessViolation :-/

Comment: So in which line exactly you get the exception?

Comment: @BlueM - after the call `ret = get_device_list(ref devices, ref i);` But this line is marked as the "Exception Line"

Comment: Your solution does work, too. But only if you change `PtrToStringAuto` to `PtrToStringAnsi` .
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, this is better. Obviously the charset needs to be fixed. Then the code will be the same as mine.  ;-)